# Printing with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

Is there any *simple* way to print to a printer with VB.NET?

Specifically, with the *console*. It seems that stuff that works with forms applications dont work with the console.

Comment: What are you trying to print? Text in a TextArea? The Window itself?

Comment: I want to print a string of text a user enters in the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lifted from http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/printvb2005.htm

```
Public Class myPrinter
   Friend TextToBePrinted As String
   Public Sub prt(ByVal text As String)
      TextToBePrinted = text
      Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument
      Using (prn)
         prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName _
            = "PrinterName"
         AddHandler prn.PrintPage, _
            AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
         prn.Print()
         RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, _
            AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
      End Using
   End Sub
   Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
      ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
      Dim myFont As New Font("Microsoft San Serif", 10)
         args.Graphics.DrawString(TextToBePrinted, _
            New Font(myFont, FontStyle.Regular), _
            Brushes.Black, 50, 50)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Called as follows:

```
Dim printer As New myPrinter
printer.prt "Hello World"
```

Comment: Did you actually try that? "Printing" is not defined for me.

Comment: That is because I am using a console application instead of a forms application. Thanks to Oded parts of the problems went away when I referenced system.drawing. And then changed "Printing." to "Drawing.Printing."

Comment: Its Monday, and it now works. an `Import Printing.Drawing` statement is needed(as well as referencing system.drawing). A small help is to use `rinting.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Item(0)` to find the printer you want instead of typing in something in `"PrinterName"`.

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835828/how-to-set-printer-properties-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class.

> Defines a reusable object that sends output to a printer, when printing from a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Is there anything like that for a _console_ application?

Comment: @Oak - Any reason why you can't use the `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace in your console application? Just add a reference in your project and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yea, my newness to vb.net. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay this post is old but from my understanding of the question, you wanted to print a string to the console, in other words :

```
System.Console.Write("My magnificent string !")
```

Comment: No, OP wanted to print to a printer - as evidenced by the fact they accepted an answer which does just that, 6 years before you posted!

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way I can think of is using a Printing Engine such as CrystalReports.

Comment: In this case using another tool does not count as simple. But thanks for the idea! Ideally simple would mean `Print("text")`