# How to print a text from textbox using Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

After the transaction, I want all my text from textbox to automatically print.
But, my code isn't working. Please someone help me to find a solution or any other way to print the text using any printer

Input : TextBox4.Text = "asdf"
Output : asdf (on a printed page)

Code

```
RequiredFieldsGovPriv()    
Printer.Print(TextBox3.Text)
Printer.EndDoc
```

Comment: Use this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168117/printing-with-vb-net). Add that class to your project, then call the prt () whenever you want to print out the text.

For printer name, you can use `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Item(0)` for the default printer of the computer, In which case your will have to import `System.Drawing.Printing`

Comment: It is not working and error occured "Settings to access printer 'PrinterName' are not valid."@HaPhan

Comment: because your computer does not have any printer that named "PrinterName". You wiil have to replace it with the name of the printer that showed in your "Devices and Printers" pane. Or replace it with the  InstalledPrinters property, as I suggested, in which case it will work with any computer that has a default printer.

Comment: Is there any way that I could print What I have input into my textbox.text? @HaPhan

Comment: just call prt(textbox.text) and it will do the thing....

Comment: @HaPhan it didn't work :(

Comment: What is the error ? I've tested it, and it worked fine in my project without any problem. What printer name did u use ? If u use `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Item(0)` for printer name, did u import `System.Drawing.Printing` ?

Comment: Everything worked. But I didn't get to work the prt(textbox.text)  part. @HaPhan

Comment: What is your whole printing code ? With that class in your project, you should be able to print by calling the prt function of the printer object. Like `Dim mprinter as new myPrinter 
mprinter.prt(textbox.text)`
and that's all it should be to printout the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

With the limitation of a comment, I can't post the code so here's the whole code to call the printer:

```
Public Class myPrinter
    Friend TextToBePrinted As String
    Public Sub print(ByVal text As String)
        TextToBePrinted = text
        Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument
        Using (prn)
            prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Item(0)
            AddHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
            prn.Print()
            RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim myFont As New Font("Microsoft San Serif", 10)
        args.Graphics.DrawString(TextToBePrinted, New Font(myFont, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 50, 50)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then, ...

```
'working code 
RequiredFieldsGovPriv() 'your sub
Dim mprinter As New myPrinter
mprinter.print(txttextbox.Text)
'Continue to work...
```

These code worked fine within my project. If you still cannot print, post your error message or a screenshot of whatever your program doing when you call the print function.